# array value with space cannot be called

Tags: jquery

i have a small problem with some code. 2 selects that are populated through the code below

```
var data_business_type = [
{"category": "Automotive","type": "Please Select Type"}, 
{"category": "Automotive","type": "Auto Accessories "},
{"category": "Real Estate","type": "Please Select"},
{"category": "Real Estate","type": "Apartment & Home Rental"}/*problem here*/
];/*around 150 more 'types' in total*/

$('#r_businessCategory').append('<option selected>Please Select Category</option>');
$('#r_businessType').append('<option selected>Please Select Type</option>');
$('#r_businessOther').hide();

var r_categories = [];
 $.each(data_business_type, function(index, item) {
  if (r_categories.indexOf(item.category) < 0) {
   r_categories.push(item.category);
 };
});

$.each(r_categories, function(index, item) {
 $('#r_businessCategory').append('<option value=' + item + '>' + item + '</option>');
});

$('#r_businessCategory').on('change', function() {
 $('#r_businessType').empty();
  var business_types = [];
$.each(data_business_type, function(index, item) {
 if (business_types.indexOf(item.type) < 0 && $('#r_businessCategory').val() == item.category) {
  business_types.push(item.type);
 };
});
```

it works at it should except when i want the 'category' to have multiple words. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rth1m59j/1/)

i'm still trying to learn so i'm not sure how to use all the brackets yet, if that changes anything.I've tried looking for a similar problem but when i try the solutions, it messes with different parts, so I haven't found a working solution yet. And sorry if it's hard to read.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Updated your code by adding the quotes at two places: https://jsfiddle.net/rth1m59j/2/

Comment: @vyx.ca: Why not add that as an answer rather than a comment?

Comment: @Chris Because while I was working on this, Barmar had just posted the correct answer. I felt the  corrected code could help the person that asked the question so I posted the link instead of "polluting" the answer board with the exact same thing as Barmar said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If an attribute value contains spaces (or some other special characters), you have to put it in quotes. It's generally a good ideal to *always* put quotes around attribute values.

```
$('#r_businessCategory').append('<option value="' + item + '">' + item + '</option>');
```

You can also use a jQuery function to create the element using structured arguments.

```
$('#r_businessCategory').append($('<option>', { value: item }));
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what i needed

Answer (score 0):

The issue is when you call val() it doesn't get anything after the space.  A quick fix, is to convert spaces to underscores, and then do it back again.  I'm sure someone else will have a better idea, but this works.

```
var data_business_type = [{
  "category": "Automotive",
  "type": "Please Select Type"
}, {
  "category": "Automotive",
  "type": "Auto Accessories "
}, {
  "category": "Real Estate",
  "type": "Please Select"
}, {
  "category": "Real Estate",
  "type": "Apartment & Home Rental"
}];
$('#r_businessCategory').append('<option selected>Please Select Category</option>');
$('#r_businessType').append('<option selected>Please Select Type</option>');
$('#r_businessOther').hide();

var r_categories = [];
$.each(data_business_type, function(index, item) {
  if (r_categories.indexOf(item.category) < 0) {
    r_categories.push(item.category);
  };
});

$.each(r_categories, function(index, item) {
  $('#r_businessCategory').append('<option value=' + item.replace(" ", "_") + '>' + item + '</option>');
});

$('#r_businessCategory').on('change', function() {
    alert($('#r_businessCategory').val());
  $('#r_businessType').empty();
  var business_types = [];
  $.each(data_business_type, function(index, item) {
    if (business_types.indexOf(item.type) < 0 && $('#r_businessCategory').val().replace("_", " ") === item.category) {
      business_types.push(item.type);
    };
  });
  $.each(business_types, function(index, item) {
    $('#r_businessType').append('<option value=' + item + '>' + item + '</option>');
  });
  $('#r_businessType').append('<option value=Other>Other</option>');
});
```